# R ggplot - getting all discrete x values to be displayed on axis in histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

With a data frame `df` and a column `col_name` I use the below function to generate histograms like in the figure below.

```
myHistogramDensity <- function(df, col_name) {
  p1 <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=col_name)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), binwidth=1, colour="black", fill="white")
  p1 <- p1 + scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) 
  p1 <- p1 + annotation_custom(tableGrob(myMinMaxMed(df, col_name), rows = NULL),
                               xmin=10, xmax=13, ymin=0.5, ymax=0.6)
  return (p1)
}
```

This gives me a histogram like below.

How do I get the x-axis to display labels for all discrete values present in `col_name` ?

[image: histogram]

Comment: You should provide the data.frame you are using. Please, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to your function (this only works if `col_name` is made up of integer values...since you said "discrete" in your request, I assume this should work)

```
x_axis_labels <- min(df[,col_name]):max(df[,col_name])

p1 <- p1 + scale_x_continuous(labels = x_axis_labels, breaks = x_axis_labels)
```